# MySQL - search and natural sorting

Tags: mysql, search, natural-sort

I have a stock of items. For example, item number (and value in the data base) is `C10364A`. The item has a barcode on it. When I scan it with a barcode scanner, the code value is `PC10364A`.

I would like to make a select input with search. When I input by barcode scanner, how to search and select this exact item?

The second question is about natural sorting.

Presented with values:

```
{ J1, J3, J18, J41, J12, L1, L13, L8 }
```

How to sort them naturally? I've tried many queries, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

#### [Q1] Searching for Items by Barcode:

To search for items by barcode, you can use the SQL `LIKE` operator to find items that match the scanned barcode. In your case, if the barcode scanner provides `PC10364A`, you can use a query similar to this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM your_stock_of_items WHERE barcode LIKE 'PC10364A';
```

This query will return all items that have a barcode matching `PC10364A`

#### [Q2] Natural Sorting

Unfortunately, MySQL does not have a built-in natural sort function, so to achieve natural sorting for values like "J1," "J3," "J18," etc., you can split the text and numeric parts and then order by them.

```sql
SELECT value FROM your_table -- or your_stock_of_items
ORDER BY 
   CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, '', -1) AS SIGNED), 
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, '', 1);
```

Here, `SUBSTRING_INDEX` is used to split the values into the text and numeric parts. Then, we can cast the numeric part to `SIGNED` to ensure numeric sorting. This will give you the desired natural sorting order for values like "J1," "J3," "J18," etc.

Comment: But with LIKE, there's problem with the P at the beginning of string.